# Dim variable from String text

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, variables, declaration

I'm trying to dim a vector inside a loop. I would like to dim the variable with a different name on each iteration, for example:

```
Dim a as String

For i = 1 to 10
    a = "vector_" & i
    Dim a() as Double
Next i
```

So, in that particular case, I need 10 Double variables: vector_1, vector_2, vector_3... Of course that code is wrong.

There is an easy way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: This attempt will not work. However, why don't you declare vector as an array? `Dim vector(1 To 10)  As Double`

Comment: May I ask for what purpose such variables need to be created?

Comment: Just didactic curiosity, but since VBA always reads the variable declarations at the beginning, I see that it is not feasible hahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare the names of the variables in a loop. The variables are to be compiled before running them, and the VBA compiler does not work with loops.

Anyway, you may consider creating a dictionary and writing the keys in the loop:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim foo As Object
    Set foo = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        a = "vector_" & i
        foo.Add a, i * i
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print foo("vector_5") 'prints 25

End Sub
```